# Requests POST with Bearer token in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, api, bearer-token, webservice-client, dynamics-business-central

I've an API secured by Bearer token to be consumed in a MVC project. I want to take the values to send from a text file every time a text file is created in a Windows folder, I used fileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder and I use a routine to read the lines from the new text file. I'm stuck creating a new record in a Business Central customer table.

```
namespace MonitorChanges
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string Path = @"D:\...", Ruta;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = Path;
            GetFiles();
        }

        public void GetFiles() 
        {
            string[] lst = Directory.GetFiles(Path);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            foreach(var sFile in lst) 
            {
                textBox1.Text += sFile + Environment.NewLine;
                Ruta = sFile;
            }
         }

        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            GetFiles();
             await GetToken(GetRuta());
        }
     
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private  string GetRuta()
        {
            return Ruta;
        }

        static async Task GetToken(string ruta)
        {

            string ClientId = "2825017b...";
            string ClientSecret = "cGO8Q~...";
            string TenantId = "36393c6b...";

            string URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent("grant_type = client_credentials" +
                                            "&scope=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default" +
                                            "&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientId) +
                                            "&client_secret=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientSecret));

            content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            
            var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                JObject Result = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                string BearerToken = Result["access_token"].ToString();

                string URL2 = "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/36393c6b.../Production/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20MX')/VistaClientes";
                HttpClient testclient = new HttpClient();
                testclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + BearerToken);
                
                var result = await testclient.GetAsync(URL2);
                
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    
                    List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
                    List<string> rows = File.ReadAllLines(ruta).ToList();
                    foreach (var row in rows)
                    {
                        string[] entries = row.Split(',');
                        //I consider entering the code here to send the values to the exposed page of Business Central


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(result.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this

```
var newClient = "{\"Name\": " + entries[0] + ",\"Name_2\": " + entries[1] + ",\"Location_Code\": " + entries[2] + ",\"Post_Code\": " + entries[3] + ",\"Country_Region_Code\": " + entries[4] + ",\"Phone_Code\": " + entries[5] + "}";
                        HttpContent dataHttpContent = new StringContent(newClient, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
                        var dataResponse = await testclient.PostAsync(URL2, dataHttpContent);
                        MessageBox.Show(await dataResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

I get this error

[Post request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV8Mj.png)

Comment: One issue I see is spaces where they do not belong: `grant_type = client_credentials`

Comment: Currently I don't have any problem with the syntax, I validated it by displaying the response in a message. 
Here: 
MessageBox.Show(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

I am really stuck on how can I insert the data into the table

Comment: You have to solve the "Bad Request" before you can do anything with the response.

Comment: I get "Bad Request" from code: "var newClient = "{\"Name\": " + entries[0] + ",\"Name_2\": " + entries[1] +..."
Could you tell me what is the correct structure of the body and how to send it as a post request?

Comment: The spaces that I mentioned can cause a bad request error so remove them. Its also never a good idea to jam strings together to create JSON. its too error prone.

Comment: I found the solution, apparently it's simpler than I expected. Thank you